# Custom JavaScript GTM Variable - How to Differentiate Views?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

[I'm following the steps in this resource](https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2014/06/19/are-you-missing-referral-traffic-universal-analytics/) to use a custom JS variable in GTM for excluding/including subdomains in referral traffic for my UA Property.

Simple example of my goal: The TLD mysite.com View should **include** blog.mysite.com as a referral source and **exclude** mysite.com as a referral source. The blog.mysite.com View should **include** mysite.com as a referral source and **exclude** blog.mysite.com as a referral source.

Per the article above, I'd have only "mysite.com" in the referral exclusion list and use JS to essentially trick GA. Here's what I've written so far for the custom JavaScript variable in GTM:

```
function () {
var theReferrer = document.referrer;
if (theReferrer) {
    var myProtocol = theReferrer.match(/(https?:\/\/)/);
    var myDomain = theReferrer.match(/\/\/mysite\.com(.+)/);
    var mySubdomain = theReferrer.match(/\/\/(.+)\.mysite\.com(.+)/);
    var myPath = "";
    
    if (mySubdomain) {
        if (mySubdomain[2]) myPath = mySubdomain[2];
        // exclude referrals from the blog.mysite.com subdomain
        if (mySubdomain[1]=="blog") { 
            return myProtocol[1]+"blog.mysite.com"+myPath;
        } 
        // include referrals from all other subdomains
        else {
            return myProtocol[1]+mySubdomain[1]+".trickga.com"+myPath;
        }
    }
    
    // include referrals from the main domain
    else if (myDomain) { 
        if (myDomain[1]) myPath = myDomain[1];
        return myProtocol[1]+"trickga.com"+myPath;
    }
}
// if the referrer isn't our main domain or subdomain, leave it alone
return document.referrer;
```

**The problem:** The above code is only applicable for "blog.mysite.com". I'd need different code for "mysite.com" to exclude/include different URLs. My TLD and subdomains are in the same Property, just different Views.

Is there a way to differentiate Views in the JavaScript? Or can I create a GTM container for each (sub)domain with their own custom JS variable?

Comment: You should really just either put both on separate properties or use the "previous page path" dimension or "host name" dimension OR use a filter to combine the hostname + pagepath so that you can see how people are navigating your site.